# How to install Mono mysql connector on ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, mono, mysql-connector

I download with wget and unzip.After Go v4.5 and install with `gacutil /i MySql.Data.dll`and itry compile with `gmcs -r:System.dll -r:System.Data.dll -r:MySql.Data.dll Sql.cs`
    And i get this error

```
error CS0006: cannot find metadata file `MySql.Data.dll' 
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem with MySql.Data package if you have problems with MySql.Data.dll you can install MySql.Data package with nuget package manager.